# Delete an internal save file - Android

Tags: java, android, save

How do I delete an internal save file dynamically in an Android application? I saved it in the default directory so I don't know the exact file path. Here is the code I used to save my files if that helps any:

public void saveAssignments(){

```
    String saveData = "";
    String FILENAME = name.replaceAll(" ", "") + ".txt";
    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Context context = getActivity();
    FileOutputStream fos;

    for(int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
            saveData = saveData + allEds.get(i).getText().toString() + ", ";
    }


    try{
        fos = context.openFileOutput( FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        try{
            fos.write(saveData.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Saved as " + FILENAME, 5000).show(); //popup message
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete file created by using `openFileOutput` method as:

```
File file=new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+FILENAME);
if(file.exists())file.delete();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tried something very similar to this and when you suggested it and it didn't work, I figured it had to be something on my end. And when I found it i was ashamed of how simple it was. As it always is. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use method

```
deleteFile(String filename)
```

on your context-object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29

Furthermore you could use

```
 String[] fileList ()
```

to query your files.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29

Answer (score 1):

You should try

`getFilesDir()` from `context` to return path or refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()). Then you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how I could use getFilesDir() from context. though I didn't use this solution, I tried it out and it worked like a charm too. You gave me some new tools to use